# How to get Service Reference Address from WCF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, linq-to-entities

I need to add a **Service Reference** to one of my applications. Now in the *Add Service Reference* box, there is an **Address** field. How do I get the Address field or URL from the WCF application to add it in my new application?

I've tried to use the URL: `http://localhost:53101/` that I got from the WCF application's properties, but it gives me this error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:53101/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. The request
>   failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains a reference
>   that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:53101/'. The remote server
>   returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed. The remote
>   server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

I've also tried to build the WCF solution, then trying to add the reference again, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Try to run you WCF projcet(by iis or iis express) and only then add the service reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my issue. I just needed to add the `.svc` file to the end of my URL and it worked. :D